# How to create multiple data frames from a huge data frame using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a very large data frame:

```
ID    A   B   C   D   E ...
1     34  56  67  98  23 ... 
2     23  67  99  45  73 ...
3     3   15  56  100 29 ...
...   ... ... ... ... ...
```

I have created several functions to process a two-column data frame. I would like to write a loop using (a list?) to generate such data frames from the large one by always incorporating the ID column. For example:

```
ID    A    ID   B   ID  C
```

Then it would be easy to pass the temporary data frames to the functions.

Thank you!

Comment: I would appreciate any idea that I could develop. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need a loop? `cbind(df$ID, df$A, df$ID, df$B...df$C)`

Comment: @RichardScriven I have asked a question: if you don't want to answer it and mark me down, fine, but don't be hostile about it.

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes there is: "So what's your question?" when I clearly wrote one.

Comment: @RichardScriven Still, thank you very much for answering another of my questions. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @user2472704 - No problem.  And I apologize if I offended you in any way.  That was not my intention. I will delete those comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given that your data frame is named veryVeryVERYLargeDF

```
lapply(colnames(veryVeryVERYLargeDF)[2:ncol(veryVeryVERYLargeDF)], function(nameOFColumnInveryVeryVERYLargeDF) cbind(veryVeryVERYLargeDF$ID, veryVeryVERYLargeDF[,nameOFColumnInveryVeryVERYLargeDF]))
```

that will give you a list of somewhatSmallerDFs, where each somewhatSmallerDF is simply the ID column from veryVeryVERYLargeDF and one of the other columns from veryVeryVERYLargeDF

Comment: Thank you! I also tried the following and it worked:

Comment: for(i in 2:ncol(df)){
  assign(paste0(i,""), df[,c(1,i)], envir = .GlobalEnv)